# How can I pan-sharpen a Landsat 8 image in GEE without losing the infrared bands?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, pansharpening

I am trying to pan-sharpen a Landsat-8 image with an 'artificial' panchromatic band derived from calculating the average of the Sentinel-2 bands with a spatial resolution of 10 meters (i.e., Red, Green, Blue, NIR).

I am doing it in GEE with the code provided in the GEE documentation on spectral transformations. The process works well and I get a Landsat image with a resolution of 10 meters as a result, but only the RGB bands are retained in the final product, as the methodology provided in the documentation involves using the 'rgbToHsv()' and the 'hsvToRgb()' methods. How can I also pan-sharpen the infrared bands so that I end up getting a pan-sharpened product with the same bands as the original product instead of just the RGB bands?

This is my code:

```
var Spain = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-3.72860936293182, 40.36209427277739],
          [-3.72860936293182, 40.236409074308916],
          [-3.46493748793182, 40.236409074308916],
          [-3.46493748793182, 40.36209427277739]]], null, false),
    geometry2 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-3.6054709910758365, 40.28987996402006]);



Map.centerObject(Spain, 10); // Polygon in Spain

var START_DATE = '2018-01-01'
var END_DATE = '2020-12-31'


////////////////////////////////////////////LANDSAT_IMAGE///////////////////////////////////


// Load a Landsat 8 top-of-atmosphere reflectance image.
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA')
            .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
            .filterBounds(Spain)
            .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
            .first()
            .clip(Spain)

print(L8)

Map.addLayer(
    L8,
    {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.25, gamma: [1.1, 1.1, 1]},
    'rgb');


////////////////////////////////////////SENTINEL-2 IMAGE////////////////////////////////////


// get one S2 image
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED") 
           .filterDate('2019-08-01', '2019-08-19')
           .filterBounds(geometry2) // Point within the polygon 'Spain'
           .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
           .first()
           .clip(Spain)
           
S2 = S2.select('B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'B8') //Only keep bands with a 10-meter resolution


//////////////////////////////////// NORMALIZE S2 IMAGE ////////////////////////////////////

// The method "hsvToRgb()", which will be used later to pan-sharpen the image, requires three normalized bands.
// The first two will be normalized later by the method "rgbToHsv()". As for the third, the code
// below normalizes the Sentinel-2 bands, from wihichit will be calculated, to the range [0-1], .

// calculate the min and max value of an image
var minMax = S2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
  geometry: S2.geometry(),
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 10e9,
  // tileScale: 16
}); 

print(minMax)

// use unit scale to normalize the pixel values
var unitScale = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    S2.bandNames().map(function(name){
    name = ee.String(name);
    var band = S2.select(name);
    return band.unitScale(ee.Number(minMax.get(name.cat('_min'))), ee.Number(minMax.get(name.cat('_max'))))
                // multiply by 100 if you want to get range 0-100
                //.multiply(100);
})).toBands().rename(S2.bandNames());
  
// add to the map
Map.addLayer(S2, {min: 0, max: 3500, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, 'original')
Map.addLayer(unitScale, {min: 0, max: 0.25, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, 'unitscaled')


////////////////////////// CALCULATE ARTIFICIAL PANCHROMATIC BAND //////////////////////////

// Calculate 'artificial panchromatic band' from Sentinel-2 bands with a 10-meter resolution.
var S2_image = unitScale.expression("((B4+B3+B2+B8)/4)",
  {
    B4 : unitScale.select('B4'),
    B3: unitScale.select('B3'),
    B2: unitScale.select('B2'),
    B8: unitScale.select('B8')
  }).rename('Panchromatic');

Map.addLayer(
    S2_image.select('Panchromatic'),
    {min: 0, max: 0.25},
    'Panchromatic');  


////////////////////////////////////// PAN-SHARPENING //////////////////////////////////////


// Convert the RGB bands to the HSV color space.
var hsv = L8.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']).rgbToHsv(); // The resulting bands are normalized

// Swap in the panchromatic band and convert back to RGB.
var sharpened = ee.Image.cat([
  hsv.select('hue'), hsv.select('saturation'), S2_image.select('Panchromatic') //Here, I include the 'artificial' Sentinel-2 normalized panchromatic band.
]).hsvToRgb();

// Display the pan-sharpened result (10-meter resolution -> same as for the panchromatic band)
Map.addLayer(sharpened,
             {min: 0, max: 0.25, bands:['red','green','blue']},
             'pan-sharpened');

print(sharpened)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach based of feedback from Noel in a [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/zyEAqsyslcE/m/BbxJhMTsAAAJ) on the Google Earth Engine Developers group. I think it should be OK to do like this. This assumes the band names are the same in `L8` and `S2`.

```
var sharpened = sharpen(L8, S2)

function sharpen(toSharpen, image) {
  var low = image.reproject(image.projection().scale(3, 3))  // Force a fixed projection of 30m.
  var offset = image.subtract(low).reproject(image.projection())
  return toSharpen
    .add(offset)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/edf145716c1b5f64c7fe5680b29848e7

**UPDATE:**
Corrected the rescaling and removed the unused kernel variable. Thanks for spotting it Diego!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only thing, it seems that you are reprojecting "image" to  a 20-meter resolution. To force a fixed projection of 30 meters you need to scale the projection by 3: "image.projection().scale(3, 3)"

Comment: One question, what is the function of the "kernel" variable within the "sharpen()" function? The variable does not seem to be used later in the function and the pan-sharpening works well without it

Comment: Thanks Diego - I've updated the answer. I was too quick in copy/pasting from the other script.

Answer (score 1):

```
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2019-08-01', '2019-08-19')
  .filterBounds(table)
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
  .first()
  .select( ['B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'B8'] );
  
  print (S2)
```

I found this mistake in the .sort case you need to use `CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE` to Sentinel instead of `CLOUD_COVER` cause this is to `LANDSAT COLLECTION`.